# How to describe a derivative of dy/dx in Modelica?

Tags: modelica, dymola

I am working on a simple model which includes a derivative of dy/dx, but in Modelica, I can't write this equation directly, I could use the combination of `x=time`and `der(y)`, but I think this is a compromise because of limitation of Modelica language.

My question is:
Is there another better method to describe derivative in Modelica?

Here is the code:

```
model HowToExpressDerivative "dy/dx=5, how to describe this equation in Modelica?"
  Real x,y;
equation 
  x = time;
  der(y) = 5;
end HowToExpressDerivative;
```

I also tried to use `der(y)/der(x)` to express `dy/dx`, but there is an error when x equals `time^2`.

```
model HowToExpressDerivative "dy/dx=5, how to describe this equation in Modelica?"
  Real x,y;
equation 
  x=time^2;
  der(y)/der(x)=5;
end HowToExpressDerivative;
```

```
Error: The following error was detected at time: 0

Model error - division by zero: (1.0) / (der(x)) = (1) / (0)

Error: Integrator failed to start model.
... "HowToExpressDerivative.mat" creating (simulation result file)

ERROR: The simulation of HowToExpressDerivative FAILED
```

Comment: Partial derivatives are only supported via functions, but I guess you know that as it was an answer to one of your own questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64262053/why-does-the-der-operator-in-modelica-apply-to-the-time-variable-only/64262535#64262535.
If that is formulated correctly, you can likely set `der_f1` = 5.

Comment: What are you trying to model where you need dy/dx? If dy/dx is known it seems quite different from the function-case.

Comment: @HansOlsson. Here is an example: the rate of change of enthalpy and density with respect to crank-angle. Like the Equation(5) in the following paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2405896316324843

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given enthalpy `h` and crank-angle `phi` you could replace `dh/dphi=...` by:

```
  der(h)/der(phi)=...
```

However, even if correct that formula will break down when the engine is standing still (`der(phi)=0`), so it is not ideal.

An alternative would be to rewrite the formulas. Looking more closely the formula seems to be:

```
  dh/dphi=(\partial a/\partial T)*dT/dphi+...
```

which suggests that they could be rewritten as:

```
  der(h)=(\partial a/\partial T)*der(T)+...
```