# Derivative as divisor gives division by zero during initialization in Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola, openmodelica, systemmodeler

I build a model that includes a derivative of `dy/dx=5`, as shown in the following segment, but the model fails during initialization in Dymola, in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65230993/12160919), it has been answered. The reason is that at time=0, the values of `der(x)` and `der(y)` are both 0. So there would be an error of division by 0.

```
model HowToExpressDerivative "dy/dx=5, how to describe this equation in Modelica?"
  extends Modelica.Icons.Example;
  Real x, y;
equation 
  x = time ^ 2;
  der(y) / der(x) = 5;
end HowToExpressDerivative;
```

Here is the result in Dymola:
[image]

But when I try the same model in the Wolfram System Modeler and OpenModelica, the model works fine.
In the Wolfram System Modeler, it uses the equation of `der(y)/der(x)=5` directly.

My questions are:

1. Why  Would the same model fail in Dymola?
2. Does Dymola NOT have the ability to do automatic symbolic manipulation to transform this equation of `der(y)/der(x)=5` into `der(y)=5*der(x)`?
3. Or the numerical solver in Dymola can't handle this kind of situation?
   [image]

[image]

Comment: For OM, it is solved as `x := time ^ 2.0`, (dummy) `der(x) := 2.0 * time`, `der(y) := 5.0 * der(x) = 10.0 * time`, and no assertion generated when eliminating the division.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dymola does currently not recognize that trivial simplification in that case (it is done in another case), not because it would be too complicated, but because Dymola uses a simple rule:

Division in the Modelica code are safe, other divisions are not considered safe.

Thus `der(x)/der(y)=5` indicates that division by der(y) is safe (even though it clearly isn't), whereas solving that equation technically involves dividing by `1/der(y)` which isn't deemed safe (as it didn't occur in the Modelica code).

Obviously the logic can be improved, but the simplest solution is to use the following rule: *don't divide in your code unless it is safe to do so.*

A benefit of following that rule is that it will be possible to check all the original equations and see that they are satisfied (up to numerical precision) - without triggering division by zero.

Comment: Is there some regulations in Modelica Specification related with this rule of not using division?

Comment: Well, the equation should be satisfied and if we cannot evaluate it that seems messy.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** In Dymola2023 the model compiles and runs correctly.

```
// Initial Section
  der(x) := 2.0*time;
  der(y) := 5.0*der(x);
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Dynamics Section
  der(x) := 2.0*time;
  der(y) := 5.0*der(x);
```